# Spring (WS) How calculate specific String hash for request body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

We have multiple Spring WS endpoints running all with similar signature

`JAXBElement<SomeResponseType> doSomthing(@RequestPayload final JAXBElement<SomeRequestType> request)`

For certain purpose we need to calculate a specific hash of the request body string.
Now it would be somehow not optimal

- to marshal the just unmarshalled object again
- to use body/string in method signature and "manually" unmarshal in method

Is there a way to obtain the request body String? We need to calculate this Hash with every method we provide and provide it to the serving method.
If the only option is to use a Filter: how to provide the value to the endpoint methods.

What is not working:

```
    HttpServletRequest curRequest =
        ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
            .getRequest();
    String body = IOUtils.toString(curRequest.getInputStream(), UTF_8);
```

body is always `curRequest.getReader` i get an exception that gerReader was already called.
I also tried to add an additional parameter to the method (@RequestBody) but this also changes the endpoint to something not working/ notbeeing ws anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a filter, you can pass in the hash via a static ThreadLocal to each method body

Comment: can you show me example code or link some?